# How to make Asynchronous code into synchronous - nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, promise

This is my nodejs api code:

```
exports.createBusiness = (req, res) => {
  const business = { name: req.body.name };
  Business.create(business)
    .then(() => {
      createSchema() // this function, i pasted below

        .then(() => {
          console.log('6 >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>');
        });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('err:', err);
    });
};
```

My function:

```
const createSchema = () => Business.findAll({
  raw: true,
}).then((data) => {
  console.log('1  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>');

  data.forEach((client) => {
    console.log('2  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>');

    postgresDB.createSchema(client.code).then(() => {
      console.log('3 >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>');

      Object.keys(postgresDB.models).forEach((currentItem) => {
        console.log('4 >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>');

        postgresDB.models[currentItem].schema(client.code).sync();
        console.log('5 >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>');
      });

      console.log('Postgres schema created');
    });
  });
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log('Warning:', err.message);
});
```

My output coming now in console by this order:

```
1  
2  
2  
2  
2  
2  
2  
2  
2  
2  
6 



3
4 
5
```

My expected output to be in console: ( i need to execute synchronously):

```
1  
2  
2  
2  
2  
2  
2  
2  
2  
2  

3
4
5

6
```

How to make this to behave synchronously using promises or callbacks?

I tried with promise.all but not working, or is async await is good to handle?

Comment: Is `postgresDB.models[currentItem].schema(client.code).sync();` synchronous or asynchronous?

Comment: asynchronous...

Answer (score 0):

You need for the promise returned by `createSchema` to resolve only once all other promises are resolved. `map` each `client` to a `Promise` and then call `Promise.all` on it. You also need to map each `currentItem` to a `Promise` and call `Promise.all` on that array of Promises as well.

Because of the `console.log`s, it looks a bit ugly:

```
const createSchema = () => Business.findAll({
  raw: true,
}).then((data) => {
  console.log('1  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>');
  const clientPromises = data.map(({ code }) => {
    console.log('2  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>');
    return postgresDB.createSchema(code).then(() => {
      console.log('3 >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>');
      return Promise.all(Object.values(postgresDB.models).map(item => {
        console.log('4 >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>');
        return item.schema(code).sync()
          .then(() => console.log('5 >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>'));
      }))
        .then(() => console.log('Postgres schema created'));
    });
  });
  return Promise.all(clientPromises);
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log('Warning:', err.message);
});
```

Without the `console.log`s, it looks a lot cleaner:

```
const createSchema = async () => {
  try {
    const data = await Business.findAll({ raw: true });
    const clientPromises = data.map(async ({ code }) => {
      await postgresDB.createSchema(code);
      return Promise.all(Object.values(postgresDB.models).map(item => (
        item.schema(code).sync()
      )));
    });
    return Promise.all(clientPromises);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Warning:', e);
  }
};
```

Comment: I tried your code  which has console.log statements